# Construction of Green's function for inhomogeneous 1D wave function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I am reading a textbook solution on the $1D$ wave PDE with a source $q(x,t)$,
$$\left(\frac 1{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)\varphi(x,t)=q(x,t)$$
We solve this equation by a finding a Green's function such that
$$\left(\frac 1{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)G(x,t;\xi,\tau)=\delta(x-\xi)\delta(t-\tau)$$
If the only waves in the systems are produced by the source, we should demand the Green's function to be *causal*, in that $G(x,t;\xi,\tau)=0$ if $t<\tau$.
To construct the *causal* Green's function, we integrate the equation over an infinitesmal time interval from $\tau-\varepsilon$ to $\tau+\varepsilon$ and so find the Cauchy data.
$$G(x,\tau+\varepsilon;\xi,\tau)=0$$
$$\frac d{dt}G(x,\tau+\varepsilon;\xi,\tau)=c^2\delta(x-\xi)$$

The above approach is taken from the textbook [mathematics for physics](https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf) page 221.

This construction is more intuitive in the sense that it does not use contour integral or Fourier transform. However, the solution does not explain how Cauchy data is derived. I am thinking of the following. I am not sure whether I am correct.

$$\int_{\tau-\varepsilon}^{\tau+\varepsilon}\frac 1{c^2}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)G(x,t;\xi,\tau)dt=\int_{\tau-\varepsilon}^{\tau+\varepsilon}\delta(x-\xi)\delta(t-\tau)dt$$

$$\frac 1{c^2}\frac {\partial}{\partial t}G(x,t;\xi,\tau)\bigg\rvert_{\tau-\varepsilon}^{\tau+\varepsilon}+\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_{\tau-\varepsilon}^{\tau+\varepsilon}G(x,t;\xi,\tau)dt=\delta(x-\xi)$$
On the LHS the second term is $0$ as $\varepsilon\to0$ since $G$ is continuous. The first term evaluates to $0$ at $t=\tau-\varepsilon$ by virtue of *causality*. So we have the second Cauchy data. Is my argument correct?
For the first Cauchy data, I believe
$$\int_{\tau-\varepsilon}^{\tau+\varepsilon}dt\int^t \frac 1{c^2}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)G(x,t;\xi,\tau)dt=\int_{\tau-\varepsilon}^{\tau+\varepsilon}dt\int^t\delta(x-\xi)\delta(t-\tau)dt$$
Am I on the right track?

Comment: Are your ICs $\varphi=\dot{\varphi}=0$?

Comment: A standard trick with 1D wave equation is the change of variables $z_\pm := x \pm ct$, so that d'Alembert's operator can be rewritten as $\square = -4\partial_{z_+}\partial_{z_-}$.

Comment: @K.defaoite From the flow of the textbook, yes, the author is talking about Cauchy condition exclusively.

Comment: @Abezhiko I am aware of that. The author first derived these Cauchy data and plugged it into the d'Alembert's formula. I am just confused how he derived these two conditions.

Comment: I am not sure where you got your last equation from.

Comment: @K.defaoite The last equation is my thought on how to get the second Cauchy data. I edited the original post to include the reference.  Feel free to have a look.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing "deriving the first/second Cauchy data". You just want the Green's function right?